# Tab closes when I come to my site from facebook only in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have shared a post on my facebook wall. When I click on that link it opens my site page and when I click on my site logo(that points to the home page), the tab is closed. This only happens in chrome.

I am not able to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the site has some java-script that is ment to close the current tab , it must be something wrong with the browser . Try Re-installing Google chrome .